# How To Base64 Encode URL Params?

Tags: php, search, get

Example we have a form :

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="Search">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

if click on Search btn url will redirect to

```
search.php?Search=parametr
```

how i can Encode This Parametr As Base64 ?

```
search.php?Search=cGFyYW1ldHI=
```

Comment: [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode). If you have woes with some specific usage, you'll have to show your code.

Comment: If this is actually about client-side form encoding, then look for javascript questions, such as [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/246801)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as [that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php). If you want to send the encoded parameter in the url you have to encode it before your html response. Else this encoding makes no sense anyway.

```
$base64 = base64_encode($parameter);
```